# Can I re-enter Hungary if my residence renewal is in process?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, dual-nationality, residency, hungary

I have two passports, Moroccan and Ukrainian. I got my Hungarian residence permit with my Moroccan passport.

Now I am planning to travel to Russia; I will use my Ukrainian passport to travel since no visa is needed.

The problem is that my residence permit for Hungary will expire while I am there. I did apply for renewal few days ago.Please note that I can enter Hungary using my Ukrainian passport, thanks to the visa free new agreement signed in June.

I have never used my Ukrainian passport to enter Europe and I don't know what to expect at the airport. Should I tell them that I live there as a citizen of Morocco and that my residency renewal papers are in process? Would they let me in without lots of questions concerning my séjour in Budapest (I am a full-time student)?

Comment: You question itself is confusing. What is the other citizenship and do you use that passport in Hungary?

Comment: @nadedja, what was your experience? Were you able to re-enter Hungary smoothly?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be deleted instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a [non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content](/legal/terms-of-service/public#licensing) under the CC BY-SA 4.0 license. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=MA&AR=HU&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=HU&selDest=Hungary&selTrans=Use%20ctrl-key%20to%20select%20or%20deselect%20transit%20point%28s%29%20above&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), the database used by Airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a residence permit
>   issued by Hungary

and

> Passports and other documents issued to residents of Hungary **must be valid on arrival**.

In other words, the airline is **not** supposed to let you board the flight back to Hungary with an expired residence permit.

So, you **must** present your Ukrainian passport when boarding the flight back, and once you get to Hungary, present both of your passports, your expired residence permit, and any document(s) proving your application for an extension. They will let you in, possibly with some delays

Comment: @Nadejda You Show your Ukrainian passport at check-in in both countries. And the Russian check-in staff will only care about whether your passport if visa-free for Hungary or not - they aren't border police

Comment: @Nadejda If this answer satisfies you, please accept it by pressing the button below the down arrow